# Minitest won't pass, although criteria are correct when checked with binding.pry

Tags: ruby, minitest, assertions

### This is the the Object being tested

```
class Ship
attr_reader :size, :x, :y, :axis

def initialize size
    @size = size
end

def length
    @size = size
end

def place x, y, axis
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @axis = axis
end

def covers? a, b
    x = @x
    y = @y

    if x == a and y == b
        return true
    else
        (@size - 1).times do
            if @axis
                x += 1
            else
                y += 1
            end
            return true if x == a and y == b
        end
        false
    end
 end
```

end

### This test will pass

```
def test_08_ship_can_be_placed_across
    ship = Ship.new(4)
    assert ship.place(2, 1, true)

    assert ship.covers?(2, 1)
    assert ship.covers?(3, 1)
    assert ship.covers?(4, 1)
    assert ship.covers?(5, 1)

    refute ship.covers?(1, 1)
    refute ship.covers?(6, 1)
    refute ship.covers?(4, 2)
 end
```

### This is the test that won't pass

```
def test_09_ship_can_be_placed_down

    ship = Ship.new(4)
    assert ship.place(2, 2, false)

    refute ship.covers?(2, 1)

    assert ship.covers?(2, 2)
    assert ship.covers?(2, 3)
    assert ship.covers?(2, 4)
    assert ship.covers?(2, 5)

    refute ship.covers?(2, 6)
    refute ship.covers?(3, 2)

  end
```

if I do binding.pry on ship.covers? with any of these parameters, I get the correct answer. For some reason the test still won't pass...

### This is the error message. Not much info...

```
1) Failure:
BattleshipTest#test_09_ship_can_be_placed_down [battleship_minitest.rb:73]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

### Binding.pry for the test that passes

```
[1] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(2, 1)
=> true
[2] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(3, 1)
=> true
[3] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(4, 1)
=> true
[4] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(5, 1)
=> true
[5] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(1, 1)
=> false
[6] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(6, 1)
=> false
[7] pry(main)> ship1.covers?(4, 2)
=> false
```

### Binding.pry for test that fails

```
[1] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(2, 1)
=> false
[2] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(2, 2)
=> true
[3] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(2, 3)
=> true
[4] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(2, 4)
=> true
[5] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(2, 5)
=> true
[6] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(2, 6)
=> false
[7] pry(main)> ship2.covers?(3, 2)
=> false
```

Comment: That one test has many assertions, which assertion fails?  Showing your `binding` line, what it returns, and the failure message for your test may give us better information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asserting a test preparation method (what I think) :

```
assert ship.place(2, 1, false)
```

`ship.place` returns axis's value since it is assigned last in the method. It works in the first case, because axis is set to true.

Comment: Is there a way to change the true/false input to a symbol or something on input and change it back to the actual true/false parameter once it goes to test?

Comment: @luke_settle : I didn't really understand that. But why do you want to assert `place` ? It just sets up the attributes and doesn't really return anything useful. If you want to test it then I think you can have a dedicated test for `place`, where you call it with certain values, and after that assert that the attributes are set to those values.

Comment: Just had to return true at the end of the place method!